# Store function in a new environment, show function details

Tags: r, function, environment

I am investigating if I can store all "user-defined-functions" in one environment, (not global environment). I manage to create the environment and send in the function inside the environment. I can also call for the function by refering to [environment$function].

However, I cannot fetch the details of the function.

**Question:** How can I view the details of the function that is located inside the environment?

My code:

```
# Create environment.
env_functions <- new.env() 

# Create function, send in to above mentioned environment.
env_functions$my_print <- function() {
print("hello")
}
```

Expected that this command should show details of the function:

```
ls.str(env_functions)
```

Results in:

`my_print : function ()` # Why are the details of the function not visible?

The functions is however possible to be called:

`env_functions$my_print()`

Results in:

```
[1] "hello"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't use the standard way of just entering the function name, if you want to see the definition of the function:

```
env_functions$my_print

function () 
{
    print("hello")
}
```